# i m unable to fetch profile pic

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i have a default profile pic and want to show it in my html but unable to get it

html code

```
    <img class="profile-pic nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="max-width: 45px; max-height:45px; border-radius: 50%;" src="{{ user.accounts.profile_pic.url }}" >
```

model

```
class Profile_Pic(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='default.png',)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile_pic(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile_Pic.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile_pic(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile_pic.save()
```

i am using signal so every time a user created he got a default profile picture

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch from "media/" then append code in templates . All images can be accessible under domain/media/image_path, in the above coe it give you the URL path to image

Comment: the files has to be fetched from databse

Comment: i did not understand please explain